# include the autoloader php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to install an SDK for OpenPay ( Mexican PayPal ) in laravel 5.2 and after doing the composer install it asks me to do this:

**Finally, be sure to include the autoloader:
require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';**

I dont know where to put that, or what to do of it, I just dont understand. If I continue without doing that everytime I try to create an instance like

```
 $openpay = Openpay::getInstance();
```

I get an error saying

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Openpay' not found
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did `composer require openpay/sdk`, composer already installed it. It's already part of your autoload. Now you can use it like this:

```
$openpay = \Openpay::getInstance();
```

Or add it to your controller first

```
...
use Openpay;

public function MyController extends Controller 
{
    $openpay = Openpay::getInstance();
}
```

Comment: it worked! thank you so much! ive been beating my head against the wall all day.